# xquery replace issue in Oracle Service Bus

Tags: xquery, osb

I'm trying to replace two backslashes with a single one within Oracle Service Bus xquery transformation with the replace function:

let $str := replace($srcStr, "\\\\", "\\"), where $srcStr holds the value "^\\d{1,4}$"

But for some reason this does not work. The result is stil "^\\d{1,4}$"

When I'm calling the same function in e.g. Altova XmlSpy this works fine: replace("^\\d{1,4}$", "\\\\", "\\") results in ^\d{1,4}

Does anybody have an idea why OSB does not match the backslashes in the source string? What could be a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug.

You can write custom regexp to workaround this bug.

```
declare function xf:replace_test($e as element()) as xs:string {
    let $str := replace("junk (\)\ junk", ".*\\.*", "\$1")
    return $str
};
declare variable $e as element() external; 
xf:replace_test($e)`
```

Comment: Hi shuttle! You are right, this is a bug of the built-in xquery processor in OSB. Could you please explain what your replace_test function exaply does? ))